# Compare if String equals a variable in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am perplexed on why something so simple isn't working, so I must be missing something obvious.

Here is my code:

```
    $store_category = '<%= terms %>';
    $store_url_suffix = '';
    if ($store_category == 'A1' ) {
      $store_url_suffix = 'coupon';
    } else {
      $store_url_suffix = '100-special-coupon';
    }
```

To note, if I echo `$store_category` it shows for instance *'A1'*, *'A2'* or *'A3'* etc as it should. The problem is the conditional expression of the if statement never evaluates to *true* so it never assigns *'coupon'* to `$store_url_suffix` and instead is always going to the else block, where it assigns *'100-special-coupon'* to `$store_url_suffix`.

Is there a reason why the conditional in this line `if ($store_category == 'A1' ) {` isn't evaluating to *true* even though echoing `$store_category` shows infact it has value *'A1'*? Am I missing a semi-colon or something here?

Comment: TBH, I don't know what this syntax is `<%= terms %>`, ASP?. Make sure there aren't any spaces or unicode introduced. What does `var_dump($store_category)` produce? `string(2)`,  `string(3)`? other? If any spaces, use `trim()`.

Comment: *"even though echoing store_category shows infact its a1?"* - You sure about your saying `a1`? `A1` is not the same as `a1`, since those are case-sensitive. You going to respond to comments? I won't be staying here much longer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry typo yes meant A1 is the actual value and that's what it echoes.

Comment: someone gave you an answer below. If that doesn't work, then you'll need to provide what I asked in comments.

Comment: `echo $var` and `var_dump($var)` are two different animals.

Comment: @Fred-ii- <%= terms %> grabs the category name in this WordPress plugin. If I echo that value of it is is for instance "A1" or "A2" and there are no special characters and no spaces. That being said if I replace <%= terms %> with A1 then the if statement does work. So all I can think of is that even though <%= terms %> outputs A1 perhaps its not a string but something special in which I need to add extra code to make sure its read as a string?

Comment: TBH, I don't know Wordpress and could be relevant to the question; I added the "wordpress" tag. Again; see the answer below, see if that solves it.

Comment: As you stated cchiera, the string '<%= terms %>' has some special meaning in wordpress... but to php, it really is just the string '<%= terms %>'.  So comparing '<%= terms %>' == 'A1' will never be true.  You need to figure out how to get the actual value 'A1' into php before you try and do any comparison.  (I'm not familiar enough with wordpress to find this information.)

Comment: @Metroids but if I store <%= terms %> into a variable say $terms and then do echo $terms and it shows a value of say A1. Confused on why I can't do an if statement that says if $terms == A1 do the following. Is there some sort of code I can run on $terms so it turns into a normal string like the one it echoes? I know trim() removes spaces, this doesn't have spaces but will use trim() maybe help anyway?

Comment: @Fred-ii- While the echo shows A1  the vardump show  string(12) "A1"  so trying to figure out what code I have to add so that vardump instead simply shows what the echo shows.

Comment: `12` is a lot longer than `2` ;-) which is why it's failing and you need to find out why.

Comment: @cchiera -- that is not what is happening.  What is happening is:  1. You echo '<%= terms %>'.  2. Before this gets to your browser, wordpress interprets that expression (it must have some sort of template renderer that replaces '<%= terms %>' with 'A1').  The php file happens before 2, so it doesn't ever see the string 'A1'.

Comment: @Fred-ii- But when I echo it, it is simply those two characters. So is there no way to simply store the value that gets echoed into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $store_category     = '<%= terms %>';  //<== COULD BE A1, A2, A3, A4, ETC... '<%= terms %>';
    $store_url_suffix   = '';
    $couponValues       = [
        'a1'=>'coupon',     
    ];

    if(array_key_exists(strtolower($store_category), $couponValues)){
        $store_url_suffix   = $couponValues[strtolower($store_category)];
    }else{
        $store_url_suffix   = '100-special-coupon';     
    }

    var_dump($store_url_suffix);        //<== string 'coupon' length(6)
```

Comment: btw, the guy is checking for `A`'s and not `a`'s. Two different animals here.

Comment: `var_dump($store_url_suffix);        //<== string 'coupon' length(6)` yeah, I asked the guy to provide that; in comments.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it!

Comment: @Poiz In your example <%= terms %> is assigned to $store_category but then in the rest of the code it never seems to look at the value of $store_category. $store_category is what holds the category name for instance A1 or A2 or A3 etc.

Comment: @Poiz I think I'm doing a poor job at explaining. If $store_category holds A1 for instance then it should store coupon in $store_url_suffix like in my example and if if doesn't, say it holds A2, A3, A4, or anything else, it should then trigger the else statement and store 100-special-coupon in $store_url_suffix.

Comment: @cchiera       the snippet in the post above would handle it exactly like that. you can as well change the values of the `a1 till a6` keys in the `$couponValues` array to reflect whatever you wish.

Comment: @Poiz I wouldn't want to hard code A2, A3 etc though since those may change in the database often. Only hard coding A1 and then if the value is ever A2 A3 B4324342 it would simply do the else statement.

Comment: @Poiz Sorry I should have mentioned earlier, yes I checked but no it does not work. Was more trying to explain why it wouldn't work based on the code. In it you hard code A1 but needs to be <%= terms %>. Since if Just put A1 into my original much shorter code it works fine. The problem is while echoing <%= terms %> shows A1 if i do a vardump of it it shows extra characters. So been trying to find a way to store what is in the echo rather than the vardump.

Comment: simply change `<%=terms %>` to `$terms`

Comment: @Poiz <%=terms %> cannot be changed. That is the variable that gets the category name. However the results that echo I need to store into a variable so that I may then run a simply if statement on it.

Comment: @cchiera      which language is that? you should rather assign the value to the `$store_category` Variable...

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but `'<%= terms %>'` is just a string, not a variable that gets category name in terms of PHP. It is just a string and 
`'<%= terms %>' == 'A1'` will never become true.

The reason why

```
$store_category = '<%= terms %>';
echo $store_category;
```

returns 'A1' must be your framework template preprocessor or something like this. Thats why echo and var_dump results much differ.

There must be a way to get real value of store category in your framework in order to use it in if condition.

I guess [this manual](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) could help you, at least try it.